# Responsive layout side by side on desktop, overlay with nav on mobile

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm looking for a responsive pattern where I have two pages side by side (or call it div's)

```
|--------|--------|
|        |        |
|  p1    |   p2   |
|        |        | 
|        |        | 
|--------|--------|
```

As I shrink the width of the page, or view it on a mobile, it collapses to a single page.
Lets say the -> in the upper right corner illustrates a link to access page two.

```
|--------|
|      ->|
|        |
|   p1   |
|        |
|--------|
```

And similar on page two, <-- to go back to page one

```
|--------|
|<-      |
|        |
|   p2   |
|        |
|--------|
```

Any idea how I can achieve this. Are there any libraries out there supporting this, like bootstrap or foundation or is this a "do it yourself". :)

Thanks, Lars

Comment: yes bootstrap will do this. However if you only want this basic 2 div set up, you could set them at 50% width by default, then use media queries to set them at 100% width at a certain breakpoint, which would make them stack on top of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by using the CSS [@media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7cm3f026/)**

```css
.div {
    width:50%;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}
.div-1 {
    background:red;
}
.div-2 {
    background:blue;
}
@media (max-width:480px) {
    .div {
        float:none;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="div div-1"></div>
<div class="div div-2"></div>
```

### [EDITED]

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sd9uk682/)**

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
a {
    color:white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.div {
    width:50%;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}
.div-1 {
    background:red;
}
.div-2 {
    background:blue;
}
@media (max-width:680px) {
    .div-p {
        width:200%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="div-p">
    <div id="div-1" class="div div-1">
        <a href="#div-2">Page 1</a>
    </div>
    <div id="div-2" class="div div-2">
        <a href="#div-1">Page 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not quite what im after, I want them to be stacked in like overlay, and pop navigation when that happens :) I was mainly wondering if there's a framework giving this for free :)

Comment: @LarsAnundskås click on the links of page 1 and page 2 in small window size - http://jsfiddle.net/cnb7ssge/